# Email verification in Firebase Console

Tags: firebase-authentication

Is there a way for administrators to see and change the status of email verification from inside the Console?  Everything I’ve found so far is based only on the client pushing a verification email from the backend and checking its status. It would be useful for the admin to get an overview of this too.

Answer (score 2):

The email verification status is not shown in the Firebase console. It's not a bad idea, so I'd definitely [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

For individual users you can use the Firebase Admin SDK to read or [change the `emailVerified` property](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user).

To get the status of all users, you can use the [`auth:export` command of the Firebase CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth#authexport).

Comment: Thanks Frank, I’ll try out filing a feature request. I’ve never done that before

Comment: There's no guarantee the requested feature will be implemented, but at the very least your vote will be heard. For things that are possible today, look at the other links I provided.